# R Programming: Issue with writeData Function and updated_origin in Excel - Incorrect Results in Specific Cases

Tags: r, openxlsx

I would like to know what's causing my problem. Whenever I write anything related to updated_origin in Excel.(Example: `writeData(wb,"sheet3",x = multiply,xy = c(c,r+2)`) It will always give me this result. (917636 (at row 6, column 3) is supposed to be in (row 5, column 3) and the value 2 in column 4 is wrong.)

[Code when I use values related to updated_origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG9cE.png)
[Excel output when I used values relatd to updated_origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17xB0.png)

However, when I write anything unrelated to updated_origin (example, `writeData(wb,"sheet3",x =column_sum,xy = c(c,r+2)`). I will get my desired result.

[Code for desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJSOi.png)
[Excel output when using values not related to updated_origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGwLP.png)

Below is the code:

---

```
addWorksheet(wb,"sheet3")  
writeData(wb,"sheet3",x = filtered_triangle)  
saveWorkbook(wb, "testing.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)  

origin <- read_excel("testing.xlsx","sheet2",skip = 1)  
origin[] <- lapply(origin,as.numeric)  

updated_origin <- read_excel("testing.xlsx","sheet3",skip = 1)  
updated_origin[] <- lapply(updated_origin,as.numeric)  

r <- 1  
c <- 2  
while(c <= ncol(origin)-1){  
  while(r <= nrow(origin)){  
    
    #column_sum <- sum(origin[,c],na.rm = TRUE)  
    
    multiply <- read_excel("testing.xlsx","sheet3",skip = 1)[r,c-1]  
    
    #column_divide <- sum(origin[,c-1],na.rm = TRUE)-multiply    
    #cumulative <- column_sum*multiply/column_divide  
    if(is.na(origin[r,c])){  
      writeData(wb,"sheet3",x = multiply,xy = c(c,r+2))  
      
      saveWorkbook(wb, "testing.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)  
    }  
    r <- r+1  
  }  
  c <- c+1  
  r <- 1  
}  
saveWorkbook(wb, "testing.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

---

[The code is use to replicate this function in Rshiny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEHKS.png)

At first I thought maybe `xy = c(c,r+2)` from `writeData(wb,"sheet3",x = multiply,xy = c(c,r+2)` was the problem. But it still doesn't help when changing it.

Comment: Please make sure to update your question to include the external dependencies you have loaded (e.g., `openxlsx`)